# Embed (a scrollable) pdf document into ppt

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am not even sure if this is possible.

I want to show a pdf document (just a series of standard A4 papers) during my presentation. I wonder if I could attach a whole pdf viewer itself to a ppt file, so that when I reach a slide, a part of that slide has an embedded pdf viewer, similar to `iframe` manner in HTML, that I could scroll and zoom and anything I would do in a pdf viewer.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Powerpoint does not support embedding HTML elements directly into a presentation. There are plugins that offer that function, but it is not native to the program or format.

Powerpoint does support embedding PDFs either as images of a single page or as embedded/linked documents, however I do not believe this supports scrolling within the presentation as you imagine.

The plugin method will only work to play the presentation on computers with that plugin installed, so you could not share or send this a PPT created this way to anywhere else and expect them to see it the way you intended. The embedding method is the only officially supported version and so will work wherever you send the file.

To embed a PDF into a PPT follow these steps:

- In the presentation go to Insert > Object.
- Select Create from File and select the PDF you wish to embed.
- Once the PDF is embedded select it and go to Insert > Action.
- Select Mouse Click and set the Object Action to Open.